# How can dependency injection by manual bean?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, dependencies

Hi i want to know dependency injection by manual registrations bean not auto bean.

this is auto register bean

```java
@Service
public class Service {
 @Autowired
 private ModelMapper mapper;
}
```

it is very simple but i want know that injection that i made config

for example)..

```java
@Configuration
public class ModelMapperConfig {

  @Bean
  public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    modelMapper
        .getConfiguration()
        .setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);

    return modelMapper;
  }
}

@Service
public class Service {
 
 // i want dependency injection... !!
}
```

thank you.

Comment: i want use ModelMapper by ModelMapperConfig .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a name to the ModelMapper bean you have created by using `@Bean(name="customModelMapper")` and then inject it with `@Autowired` and `@Qualifier("customModelMapper")`. So your service would look like this :

```
@Service
public class Service {
 @Autowired
 @Qualifier("customModelMapper")
 private ModelMapper mapper;
}
```